# Lower sound from 1st input when second input has sound

Tags: microcontroller, audio, integrated-circuit, sound

I'm looking for an IC/device/... that can switch between sound inputs. 
Lets say that I play music through audio jack 1, and a GPS is connected to audio jack 2. I'd like the IC/device to lower/kill the audio coming from jack 1 and play the gps sound (being the voice commands by the GPS) from jack 2. When the GPS is done speaking, the music should start playing again after some time.

Is there such a device/switch/ic/...? Does the concept described above have a name?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the input device? Please give us more details. In any case, it sounds like you need some sort of gating device to prioritise one of the inputs over the other. These can be found on DJ mixing desks to prioritise the MIC channel over the music.

Comment: http://www.thatcorp.com/datashts/dn102.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was looking for the term: ducker. That circuit is awesome! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DJ mixing desk device (mentioned by F. Bloggs) used to be called a "ducker" as it 'ducked' the music level below the voice level. If you can't find a ready-made device, you should be able to find a suitable circuit on a web search. You'll also find terms describing how quickly it ducked - too sudden doesn't sound too nice - and the release time - how long the silence has to be before the music starts to fade back up - and the release rate - how quickly it fades up once it has started.

The ducker is also a feature on many building PA systems to mute the music during paging.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ducking may help.

Comment: A 'ducker' circuit is absolutely what I was looking for.