# Analog signal detection

Tags: analog, signal

I have an audio mixing circuit that in a simplified diagram looks like this:

[image: Simplified mixer diagram]

Sounce source A goes straight to the headphones (impedance ~300 ohm). Sound source B is buffered and amplified before being mixed.

I have a circuit that can shutdown/mute the buffers for sound source B because I need to prioritize sound source A into the headphones. Sound source B should mute is signal at the mix contains the signal from source A. However I am trying to figure out a way to tell them apart in order to reliably operate this function.

I cannot buffer sound source A, it is a closed system. The overall system that source B is connected to has its own power supply and is allowed to fail but shall not interfere with the operation of source A into the headset.

Hint: Use of a microcontroller and embedded software is a valid solution if it helps determine the signal differences.

**update:** I agree with @transistor's answer that a ducking circuit will achieve what I am looking for. However, the question is, is it possible to set up a reliable trigger to engage the ducking circuit to mute signal B when signal A is present given the layout in the picture above?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Zout  possibly 0.01to 1 Ohm to mix out to 300 Ohms, you may add 10 Ohms in series from each source to each side and hope there is no loading issue.

Comment: Question is: how to know if mix signal has signal a only or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is often called a "ducker" in DJ applications or a "VOX" (voice) switch in 2-way radio applications.

Since your B signal is fed onto the same line you can't tell by monitoring the mixed line alone. You might get it to work by monitoring the difference between the B input and the mixed line and switching if they differ (due to A turning on).

The right way to do it is to buffer signal A and monitor the A signal *before* the buffer and feed this into the ducker circuit.

Links:

- [Lower sound from 1st input when second input has sound](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/204481/lower-sound-from-1st-input-when-second-input-has-sound/204538#204538).

---

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzMORr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. One channel of a channel A priority circuit.*

This isn't a full design but may prompt you to figure out a solution.

How it works:

- OA1 is a [differential amplifier](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_5.html). If R1 = R2 and R3 = R4 then

$$ V_{OUT} = \frac {-R_3}{R_1} (V_B - V_A) $$

- You would need to get the gains matched (and R5 is a liability in managing this) so a pot may be required somewhere.
- If \$ V_A = V_B \$ then A is silent and only B is active. \$ V_{OUT} = 0 \$ or close to it.
- If \$ V_A \neq V_B \$ then there must be signal on A. \$ V_{OUT} \neq 0 \$ and the difference signal can be used to trigger CMP1. Its output will switch. This can be used to disconnect SW1. (Circuit left to OP.)
- R7 is included as a reminder to check the comparitor data sheet. Some have open-collector outputs and require a pull-up.

Comment: I appreciate the post but I'm still looking for a way to engage the vox circuit.

Comment: See the update for a suggestion.

Comment: Wow, I think this can work. I've not had a chance e to play with differential amplifiers before so here's a great excuse for it. I presume the +1 between Vb and R5 is a unity gain buffer?

Comment: Correct, but as I pointed out R5 will mess this up as it will attenuate the signal. The buffer may be a good place for the potentiometer. Use it to increase the gain so that with B only you have Va = Vb. I meant to write that you need a time-delay on the release of the B mute since the comparator is only detecting positive signals and you don't want "pumping" of the B signal which is a problem when DJs set the release too short. You might find a VOX circuit with the comparator and mute switch already built in.